# Rails - does capybara matchers process ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, matcher

I was wondering if Capybara matchers process ERB. For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Random</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= "Hello World" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I run `expect(page).to have_content("Hello World")` in my RSpec file, will it return true or false? If false, is there a way to make Capybara process the ERB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara checks what returns from the server. Since the ERB is processed on the server (*before* it is sent to the client) - Capybara sees *only* the output after ERB has done its job.

To answer your question - capybara should return `true` to `page.has_content("Hello World")`